# Sort array by count results in Php

Tags: php

I want to sort the result based on a result count in php loop.My code in templates looks like this

```
<?php foreach($groups as $group): ?>
        <?php if(count($group->getAllgroupmember()) > 0): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $group->id ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $group->name ?></td>
                <td><?php echo number_format(count($group->getAllgroupmember())) ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endif ?>
        <?php var_dump(count($group->getAllgroupmember())) ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
```

The var_dump result

```
int(1) int(1) int(4) int(0) int(1) int(0) int(0) int(0) int(0) int(0) int(1) int(0) int(0) int(0) int(0) int(0) int(0) int(0) int(0) int(0) int(0) int(0) int(0) int(0)
```

How to sort based on result count? The highest value(4) should be in 0 position. I tried usort function

```
<?php foreach(usort($groups) as $group): ?>
        <?php if(count($group->getAllgroupmember()) > 0): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $group->id ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $group->name ?></td>
                <td><?php echo number_format(count($group->getAllgroupmember())) ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endif ?>
        <?php var_dump(count($group->getAllgroupmember())) . "<br>" ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
```

But no luck..Any ideas how fullfill this?

Answer (score 2):

[usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) requires a callable as the second parameter. See below:

> ```
> <?php
> $usort($groups, function($a, $b){
>     $countA = count($a->getAllgroupmember());
>     $countB = count($b->getAllgroupmember());
>     if ($countA  == $countB) {
>         return 0;
>     }
>     return ($countA > $countB) ? -1 : 1;
> });
> ?>
> ```

```
<?php foreach($groups as $group): ?>
        <?php if(count($group->getAllgroupmember()) > 0): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $group->id ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $group->name ?></td>
                <td><?php echo number_format(count($group->getAllgroupmember())) ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endif ?>
        <?php var_dump(count($group->getAllgroupmember())) . "<br>" ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
```

The sort function I crafted above gets the member count for each of the passed in objects and sorts the array using those numbers in descending order.

I've added a link to the usort method above. You should be able to further understand the function I crafted after you review the usort documentation.

I hope this helps.